# How do I look for ">" in a file using shell script?

Tags: grep, sh

I am trying to look for ">" character in a CSV using the `grep` command as follows:

`grep ">" test_file.csv`

`grep \> test_file.csv`

However, both these commands yield no results. I know for a fact that several instances of this character appear in this file. I am pretty sure this issue is coming up because ">" is also used as the stream input character. How do I search for ">" and get results successfully?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `echo $'foo\nbar > baz\nquux' > test_file.csv ; grep ">" test_file.csv` correctly returns `bar > baz`. And it can't be because it is the stream input character, because it is quoted. Unless you're using it nested, in which case you have to show a [example].

Comment: If you are unsure why a character match is not working, especially with grep, a quick extra attempt you can try is to use square brackets: `grep '[>]' file`. This works in 99% of the time. Yes, there are ways with flags to modify the behaviour of grep, but if you need a quick solution, the square brackets beat reading the man page.

Comment: `grep ">"` [works well](https://ideone.com/HwXFWU).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following command

```
grep -F '>' application.log
grep -e '>' application.log
```

-F stand for input as fixed string.

-e make string as a pattern.

To print line number as well you can use -n flag.

Comment: Using -F fixed the issue for me. Thanks

Comment: Please upvote the answer so that others can also consider it right